# How to compare recorded skeleton with live skeleton by using kinect sensor?

Tags: skeletal-animation, kinect

I am developing project where user will perform movement in front of the kinect. Up to now I can calculate the angles between joints and can detect body parts. My second approach is recording these movements and store in database and then patient will try to follow this motion. Now I need to compare live skeleton with recorded skeleton. I am working with c#. This screenshot gives what i done up to now.

My Question is how to save motion by using kinect and how to compare save motion with live skeleton. If there any reference please let me know.

[image]

[image]